# python 3 import from module without specifying the class itself

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following structure in my project:

```
.../project_root/custom/__init.py__
.../project_root/custom/myclass.py
.../project_root/test.py
```

`__init.py__` is empty
in test.py when I write

```
from custom.myclass import myclass
```

myclass is loaded correctly and I can call its methods

but when I try to import it like this:

```
from custom import myclass
```

I get error:

```
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

when trying to initialize the class

I was unable to find any valuable information on this, further more what is I want to import it like for example the sys package, is that even possible?

```
import myclass
```

myclass.py

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.text = 'test'

    def print(self):
        print(self.text)
```

test.py:

```
from custom import myclass

x = myclass()

print(x)
```

full stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "..project-root/test.py", line 3, in <module>
    x = myclass()
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Comment: I think that error is from ```instance = myclass()``` in your test. You must change it to ```instance = myclass.myclass()```. You have module myclass, which has class myclass inside. You must say python which one to call. If you are importing module and want to call class - reference to it by myclass.myclass

Comment: See my edits. isnt custom the module?

Comment: of cause, custom is a module. But file myclass.py forms submodule there. If you don't want submodule you can place all code from mycalsss.py into ```__init__.py```, or place ``import myclass from myclass``` into ```__init__.py```